# How to replace something in a JSON string with the contents of a variable?

Tags: python, json

Sorry, I am very new to web scraping and JSON, so this might seem very stupid.
I am trying to add my own variable into the request payload I got off of the website I am trying to get the data from. Originally, my data looked like this:

```
{"query":"{\n    viewer {\n      productTemplate(slug: \"yeezy-boost-350-v2-tailgate-fx4348\") {\n        id\n     etc...
```

I want to replace the link that is provided in the slug: with my python variable. I created a `for` loop and nested the json string inside of it, which gets many different slug: values. I scrape the data by using

```
import requests


r = requests.post(url2, headers=headers, json=data)
for i in r.json()["data"]["viewer"]["productTemplate"]["used_products_ex_goat_clean"]:
    print(i["price_cents"])
```

I have tried many different ways of replacing the slug value with my own values, with my last attempt reading:

```
(slug: slugquote)
```

where slugquote outputs `\"yeezy-boost-350-v2-tailgate-fx4348\"` earlier.

I'm very sorry, I'm positive none of this makes any sense / is stupid to anyone who actually knows what they are doing, I've tried every method I know in python to put the variable in there, in many different formats.

My error that I most commonly get is `KeyError: 'data'`. I'm 99% sure this is just because it can't find it because the slug is not pointing to the right area.

EDIT: I just cleaned up the full request payload, narrowing it down to a single line.

```
 data = {"query":"{\n    viewer {\n      productTemplate(slug: \"yeezy-boost-350-v2-tailgate-fx4348\") {\n        used_products_ex_goat_clean {\n          id\n          slug\n          price_cents\n          size\n          is_instant_shippable\n          outer_picture\n}\n      }\n    }\n  }"}
```

Thank you for all the answers so far. This is the smallest payload I could make that contains all of the information I need. On every different page I want to scrape that I have the slug for, all of the payloads contain the exact same structure that are able to use the one above. My end goal is to be able to change this data into

```
 data = {"query":"{\n    viewer {\n      productTemplate(slug: myVar) {\n        used_products_ex_goat_clean {\n          id\n          slug\n          price_cents\n          size\n          is_instant_shippable\n          outer_picture\n}\n      }\n    }\n  }"}
```

to simplify the entire process. Is it even possible to do this on this source payload? I hope this helps.

Comment: Could you place a formatted example of the json you are talking about? I got a vague idea, but that would be very helpful to answer your question!

Comment: are you operating on the json data as a string?  have you thought of transform it into a dictionary (`mydict = json.loads(jsonstring)`), modifying what you need using `mydict[mykey] = myslug`, then `jsonstring = json.dumps(mydict)` to get the now updated json string.  i.e. and It's not clear if you are doing this from your code, but the last thing you want to do is loop through the content of a json string to modify it with string functions.

Comment: Have you printed the result of `r.json()` to examine it? Is that what you shared at the beginning of your post? Remember, once you get the data from `r.json()`, or through the json module, you have a dictionary, so JSON becomes irrelevant.

Comment: trim out the json data to something much smaller, maybe with a few slugs (to show nesting/matching issues), then show us which slug you are trying to modify, along with your attempted code and you will get better answers.  you can use something like http://json.parser.online.fr/ to format the json to with indentations and validate your simplified example.